# (Searching in a table) Whats the best practice?

Tags: javascript, java, php, sql, database

(Searching in a table) Whats the best practice ?
 Filter data with JavaScript in a table  or  resend a query with filter condition and get data already filtered form database ?

Comment: Depends on how many rows are in your table. More than 3k and I would use Ajax.

Comment: if ur result gets over 1000 rows JS will maybe be slower than make another ajax call

Comment: Your SQL Server is most likely better equipped for handling great amounts of data than whatever you can code in JS, I would go with the latter solution

Comment: Filtering on the database end of things is usually quicker, however if you're only filtering 10 queries then it is overkill, it all depends on the number of queries you're dealing with.

Comment: of course it is necessary to had indexed that table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course to filter with JavaScript. Putting an extra-pressure on server is always a bad idea. You have only one server and many clients, let them work.

Comment: How can you say that? If you have more than 10K records, what will happen? You want to send all the records to the client (traffic concern) and then filter them?

Comment: @SamanGholami well, everyone decides what's the biggest concern in his particular situation. Author didn't tell how much records he have, nor any other circumstances. So in a nutshell - yes, it's better to filter on frontend if you have such ability. Poorly formulated question, not my fault.